# Zip file contents in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, zip

We have a function that gets the list of files in a zip file and it works standalone and in Lambda until the fire is larger than 512 meg.
The function needs to get a list of files in the zip file and read the contents of a JSON file that should be in the zip file.

This is part of the function:

```
try:
    s3_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=filename)
    #s3_object = s3_client.head_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=filename)
    #s3_object = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name=bucketname, key=filename)
except:
    return ('NotExist')

zip_file = s3_object['Body'].read()
buffer = io.BytesIO(zip_file)
# buffer = io.BytesIO(s3_object.get()['Body'].read())

with zipfile.ZipFile(buffer, mode='r', allowZip64=True) as zip_files:

    for content_filename in zip_files.namelist():
        zipinfo = zip_files.getinfo(content_filename)
        if zipinfo.filename[:2] != '__':
            no_files += 1
            if zipinfo.filename == json_file:
                json_exist = True
                with io.TextIOWrapper(zip_files.open(json_file), encoding='utf-8') as jsonfile:
                    object_json = jsonfile.read()
```

The get_object is the issue as it loads gets the file into memory hand obviously the large of the file it is going to be more than it's available in Lambda.
I've tried using head_object but that only gives me the meta data for the file and I don't know how to get the list of files in the zip file when using head_object or resource.Object.

I would be grateful for any ideas please.

Comment: What hits the 512MB barrier? Is it the size of the Zip file, or the uncompressed size of the JSON file _within_ the Zip file?

Comment: It has to have the ability to manage 5TB files as that is the limit for an object on S3.

Comment: Where are the files coming from? Another pragmatic option would be to write a second file with the same name but different extension that is just the "index" of files within the ZIP. So if you have `abc.zip` you would also have a `abc.index` which contains a list of files in the ZIP in whatever format that is best for you.

Comment: The files are coming from an application that we wrote. The zip file and json file used to be separate but we added the json file to the zip file to be more efficient but as we can't read the json file in the zip file without downloading and unzipping the zip file, we might have to go back to having separate files.

Answer (score 0):

It would likely be the `.read()` operation that consumes the memory.

So, one option is to simply **increase the memory allocation** given to the Lambda function.

Or, you can `download_file()` the zip file, but Lambda functions are only given 512MB in the `/tmp/` directory for storage, so you would likely need to mount an Amazon EFS filesystem for **additional storage**.

Or you might be able to use [smart-open · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/) to **directly read the contents of the Zip file from S3** -- it knows how to use `open()` with files in S3 and also Zip files.

Comment: Fun fact: they bumped `/tmp` to 10GB last week  Furthermore, another solution would be do to all the processing in memory. That should also be faster than writing to disk. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/

Comment: Thanks John. It needs to have the ability to manage 5TB files as that is the limit for an object on S3. All I need to do is get a list of files in the zip files, count the number of them and ten when we get the JSON file, read the contents of the JSON files. The JSON will be very small, Kb.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for the link, it's great that the storage has been increased for Lambda!

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but too long for comments.

It is possible to download only part of a file from S3, so you should be able to grab only the list of files and parse that.

The zip file format places the list of archived files at the end of the archive, in a [Central directory file header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Central_directory_file_header).

You can download part of a file from S3 by specifying a range to the [GetObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html#API_GetObject_RequestSyntax) API call. In Python, with boto3, you would pass the range as a parameter to the [get_object()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) s3 client method, or the [get()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.get) method of the Object resource.

So, you could read pieces from the end of the file in 1 MiB increments until you find the header signature (0x02014b50), then parse the header and extract the file names. You might even be able to trick Python into thinking it's a proper .zip file and convince it to [give you the list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist) while providing only the last piece(s). An elegant solution that doesn't require downloading huge files.

Or, it might be easier to ask the uploader to provide a list of files with the archive. Depending on your situation, not everything has to be solved in code :).

Comment: Thank you. Sounds like a good way to look at it. Do you know if there are any examples of this please? I have a Fargate code that unzips and un tars files and that seems to be having the same issue when we use get_object() and read(). It attempt to load the file into memory and obviously this won't work for large files. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't have any examples at hand, sorry.

Comment: I am trying to get part of the file but the Range is not working. It is reading the entire file.

start_byte = 0
stop_byte = 10
s3_object = s3_client.get_object(
            Bucket=bucketname, Key=filename, Range='bytes{}-{}'.format(start_byte, stop_byte-1))